# Не получается передать переменную из JavaScript в PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Столкнулся с проблемой. Пытаюсь передать значение атрибута id кнопки.

HTML:

```
// вырезанный фрагмент из кода, JS файл и jQuery подключены
<form>
    <button type"submit" id="variable" class="sendBtn">Send</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.sendBtn').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    let variable = $('.sendBtn').attr('id');
    console.log(variable); // на этом моменте идёт вывод атрибута в консоль, всё ОК

    $.ajax({
        url: '../vendor/approve.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: variable,
        success (data) {
           console.log('Ok') // на этом этапе в консоль выводится Ok
        }
    })
});
```

Попытка в PHP:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['variable'])) {
        header('Location: /home.php') // к примеру
    } else {
        header('Location: /error.php')
    }
?>
```

Если пытаюсь каким-либо образом использовать $_POST['variable'] в коде, то он "не существует".

Comment: не существует конечно, не надо в пост просто строку пихать. `data: { variable: variable }` сделайте, тогда и получите соответственно массив на входе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй так

```
let variable = $('.sendBtn').attr('id');

let param = {
        variable: variable
    };

$.ajax({
        url: '../vendor/approve.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: param,
        success (data) {
           console.log('Ok') // на этом этапе в консоль выводится Ok
        }
    });
```